# Deleting element jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm noob in programming, 
i searched for a solution but but to no avail,
The script does not work when i add

```
else
```

instruction. What is wrong?

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var popID = "popup1";
        var popWidth = "44%";
        var popHeight = "30%";

        if ($(this).scrollLeft() <= 500) {

            $("#container").append('<div id="drawing"></div>');
            $("#drawing").css("background-color", "#f04").animate({
                top: '84%',
                left: '10%'
            });

            //Fade in the Popup and add close button
            $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({
                'width': String(popWidth),
                'height': String(popHeight)
            }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

            //Fade in Background

            $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.

            $('#fade').css({
                'filter': 'alpha(opacity=80)'
            }).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer 

            return false;
        };

        else if ($(this).scrollLeft() >= 600) {
            $('#war').remove()
        }

        //Close Popups and Fade Layer

        $('body').click(function () { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...

            $('#fade, a.close').fadeOut(function () {
                $('#fade, .popup_block').remove();
            }); //fade them both out
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: too many semi-colons. If statements do not need to be ended in a `;` Look at the line before the else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem with your code

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var popID = "popup1";
        var popWidth = "44%";
        var popHeight = "30%";

        if ($(this).scrollLeft() <= 500) {

            $("#container").append('<div id="drawing"></div>');
            $("#drawing").css("background-color", "#f04").animate({
                top: '84%',
                left: '10%'
            });

            //Fade in the Popup and add close button
            $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({
                'width': String(popWidth),
                'height': String(popHeight)
            }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

            //Fade in Background

            $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.

            $('#fade').css({
                'filter': 'alpha(opacity=80)'
            }).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer 

            return false;
        }
        else if ($(this).scrollLeft() >= 600) {
            $('#war').remove()
        }
```

There is a semi-colon before the else if which doesnot allow the script to run. It will give error in case you run with semi-colon before else-if. If-else-if is construct in the programming with parentheses defining the scope of each condition. They never end up with semicolons.